# Text to Columns in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to convert entire column to the text delimited. 
Tried this code:

```
y.Sheets("csv").Range("A:A").NumberFormat = "@"
```

But with this code I get the result like in the picture.

[image: result]

However, I want to get the result like this : 
[image: Should be]

As you see I am unable to make the vba code for the last step in the Text to Columns Menu where we choose "Text" there.

I have also tried this code :

```
'Dim myRange As Range
'Set myRange = y.Sheets("csv").Range("A1:A20") ' you may need to qualify the range with sheet name, etc.

   ' myRange.TextToColumns Destination:=myRange, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    'TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    'Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=True, OtherChar:="-"
```

But here also I am unable to control last step (where I can choose Text). Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.texttocolumns, you can provide column data types as an array of two-element arrays, so try passing something like `FieldInfo:=array(array(1, xlTextFormat))`. Alternatively, it might be easier to apply `@` number formatting to column A after the column has been split.

Comment: That worked like charm. Thank you very much.